# How to pass the address of a matrix through a structure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, pthreads, structure

I'm trying to pass these matrices to a pthread using a structure.

Matrix Allocation

```
double **A = (double **)malloc(size_matrix * sizeof(double*));
double **B = (double **)malloc(size_matrix * sizeof(double*));
double **C = (double **)malloc(size_matrix * sizeof(double*));
for(i = 0; i < size_matrix; i++){
    A[i] = (double *)malloc(size_matrix * sizeof(double));
    B[i] = (double *)malloc(size_matrix * sizeof(double));
    C[i] = (double *)malloc(size_matrix * sizeof(double));
}
```

Passing the Structure

```
for (t=0; t<thread_num-1; t++) {
    thread_data[t].start = thread_count;
    thread_data[t].end = thread_count + rows_per_thread-1;
    thread_data[t].A_Matrix = *A;
    thread_data[t].B_Matrix = *B;
    thread_data[t].C_Matrix = *C;
    thread_count += rows_per_thread;
}
```

The Structure

```
typedef struct {
int start;
int end;
double *A_Matrix;
double *B_Matrix;
double *C_Matrix;
} thread_data_t;
```

The routine executed by the thread.

```
void *thread_mul(void *arg)
{
thread_data_t *td = (thread_data_t *) arg;
int i,j,k;


for ( i=td->start; i<=td->end; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<size_matrix; j++){
        for(k=0;k<size_matrix;k++){

            td->*C[i][j]+=td->*A[i][k]*td->(*B[k][j]);
        }
    }

}


pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The problem is when the routine tries to execute it doesn't find the matrix in

```
td->*C[i][j]+=td->*A[i][k]*td->(*B[k][j]);
```

I get an error saying it expects something between the -> and the *.

Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the declaration of the matrix members needs to have two asterisks, because it's a pointer to pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;
    double **A;
    double **B;
    double **C;
} thread_data_t;
```

The syntax `td->*C[i][j]` is incorrect: the dereference operator (i.e. the asterisk `*`) is not necessary, because square brackets `[]` decrease the level of indirection by one:

```
td->C[i][j] += (td->A[i][k]) * (td->B[k][j]);
```

Note: this is not relevant to your problem, but in cases when you need to dereference a pointer stored in a `struct`, you apply the asterisk to the result of the expression, like this: `*(td->ptrC[i][j])`. The parentheses are not required there, because `->` has higher precedence, but I put them in anyway to illustrate what is going on.

Comment: @djst2d You are welcome! Try this out and see if it works. If it does, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would earn you a new badge on stack overflow, and let others know that your problem is solved.